# Checking if input is not numeric - !is_numeric

Tags: php, forms, validation

I have a short shop form. You can buy there some pens, mugs etc.

After you put a number of items you want to buy I am trying to validate the input information and if it is not correct just change it into 0.

Looks like the `!is_numeric` function doesn't work, because it always makes the amount 0.

Any help please? Does `!` work with this function at all?

```
$mugAmount = Input::get('mugAmount');

if(!isset($mugAmount) OR $mugAmount = NULL OR !is_numeric($mugAmount) OR $mugAmount < 0){
               $mugAmount = 0;
           };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of this `$mugAmount = NULL`. This should be `$mugAmount == NULL`.

`=` and `==` means totally different things ;)

ps: besides you can remove this comparison to NULL because if it is NULL then `!isset($mugAmount)` will be true :)

Comment: God damn these beginners difficulties. Thanks nospor! and best wishes for our Polish php forums dude :)

Comment: Hehe, yes, best wishes for them.... ;)